# SQL syntax ERROR in STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysqli

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' STR_TO_DATE('1988-02-04','%m/%d/%Y'),

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO customer_registration( ";
$sql .= "CUSTOMER_FNAME, CUSTOMER_LNAME, CUSTOMER_DOB, APARTMENT, ";
$sql .= "STREET, CITY, PROVINCE, POSTAL_CODE, EMAIL, PHONE, SIGN_IN_DATE ";
$sql .= ") VALUES (";
$sql .= " '{$fname}', {$lname}, STR_TO_DATE('$dob','%m/%d/%Y'), {$apt}, {$city}, {$province}, {$postalCode}, {$_email}, {$phone}, {NOW()}";
$sql .= ")";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

What seems to be the error ?

Comment: Add quotes for {$lname}, {$apt}, {$city}, {$province}, {$postalCode}, {$_email}, {$phone}. Use PDO

Comment: That did seem to work for all other variables except for STR_TO_DATE and NOW

Comment: Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Show the table structure, filed and column types

Comment: It worked by removing {} from the function NOW()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to work, all I had to do was add the quotes and remove the quotes off the functions.

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO customer_registration( ";
$sql .= "CUSTOMER_FNAME, CUSTOMER_LNAME, CUSTOMER_DOB, APARTMENT, ";
$sql .= "STREET, CITY, PROVINCE, POSTAL_CODE, EMAIL, PHONE, SIGN_IN_DATE ";
$sql .= ") VALUES (";
$sql .= " '{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$dob}', '{$apt}', '{$street}', '{$city}', '{$province}', '{$postalCode}', '{$_email}', '{$phone}', NOW()";
$sql .= ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use `strtotime()` on your first date. Then `date('Y-m-d')` to convert it back.

**2)** Use Single quote `'` in your values. Like `'{$lname}'`

**3)** Remove Single quote `'` from Now()

```
<?
$dob = strtotime($dob);
$dob = date('%m/%d/%Y',$dob);

$sql  = "INSERT INTO customer_registration( ";
$sql .= "CUSTOMER_FNAME, CUSTOMER_LNAME, CUSTOMER_DOB, APARTMENT, ";
$sql .= "STREET, CITY, PROVINCE, POSTAL_CODE, EMAIL, PHONE, SIGN_IN_DATE ";
$sql .= ") VALUES (";
$sql .= " '{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$dob}', '{$apt}', '{$city}', '{$province}', '{$postalCode}', '{$_email}', '{$phone}', NOW()";
$sql .= ")";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

?>
```